# logical flow in SQL subqueries including relations from outer queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm having difficulty understanding the logical flow of subqueries that include the relations from the outer query. I was thinking that the subqueries will process their information first and then use their information in the outer query. For example:

```
Select distinct course_id
From section
Where semester - 'Fall' and year = 2017 and
course_id in (Select course_id
              From section
              Where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2018);
```

will first calculate the inner query and result in a relation including course_ids that are open in 2018 Spring semester. Then proceeding to the outer query, it will find tuples with semester - 'Fall' and year = 2017 that have course_ids within the relation from the inner subquery.

However, for cases in which the inner subquery uses the outer subquery in the where clause, I do not understand how the logic proceeds. For example:

```
Select course_id
From section as S
Where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2017 and
      exists (Select *
              From section as T
              Where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2018 and
              S.course_id = T.course_id);
```

In this case, calculating the inner subquery first will only give the tuples which have semester = 'Spring' and year = 2018, as S and T will have identical course_ids.
In order for this to make sense, I realized that the tuples will have to be proceeding from the outer query to the inner query-- that is, find tuples that are semester = 'Fall' and year = 2017 and amongst these tuples compare their course_ids in the where clause inside the subquery.
Would my understanding be correct?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans for those queries?

Comment: is there a certain way that I can view the execution plans?

Comment: I have merely began studying SQL so I am not familiar with the execution plans

Comment: How can one thing happen 'logically' before the other when they produce the same logical outcome?